# How do I authenticate when I download web mail into Python?

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

I want to have a web mail link address and download it in python and I want to authenticate once (e.x. cookies) and open that file

```
import urllib.request
import os
import urllib
url = 'https://......'
save_name = "test"
path = "c:/"
mem = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
with open(path+save_name,mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(mem)
    print("completed")
os.system(path+save_name)
```

Comment: if you want to download mail from mail server then maybe better use standard module [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) or [poplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html), or maybe external module like [emailclient](https://github.com/aesptux/mailclient)

Comment: if you want to login to web page then you have to use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check what browser sends to server. Every web page may have different login form so there is no direct answer for this problem.